# multidimensional Array in node.js storing a mysql database

Tags: java, node.js, discord

I'm trying to limit database hits on my RPG Bot in DISCORD and so decided to store an initall lookup of my database as an internal array so that when doing data look up i can just loop through my array and look for where

UserList[i][ID] is equal to the id of the responding user.
This is how my database lookup works i'm just offloading it to an array so 
Id.Of.comment.owner = SomeNumber
fetch from mysql database user whos id is SomeNumber

but now i'll be doing more of a
For (i =0; i < userlist.length; i++)
if userlist[i][ID] = Somenumber 
--Do something

And i just want to make surei understand how i set up a multi dimensioal array in node.js

Obviously i'll have to prock the database one and loop through that 
but what is the syntax to init and fill is it just

```
var Userlist[][];
```

then

```
for (h=0; h< sizeofdatabase; h++)
UserList[h][id]
...
UserList[h][PLACEHOLDER_xp_percent]
UserList[h][PLACEHOLDER_rank]
UserList[h][PLACEHOLDER_rank_total]
```

Answer (score 1):

so after talking on discord it turned out that Maps were the way to go, as i haven't found any good map references let me share what i did.

first off the initilizer

```
exports.UserSkillList = new Map();
```

Now i put mine in my setting.js where I keep all my globals this the 'exports' but if you don't need it globally it's just

```
let UserSkillList = new Map();
```

now lets populate it, i'm populating mine from my user database and i'm just going to assume you know how to make a sql loop, for my purposes rows_db is the array for each pass through my database

```
                for (var i = 0; i < rows_db.length; i++) {
                    settings.UserList.set(rows_db[i].id, {
                    Gender: rows_db[i].Gender,
                    Height: rows_db[i].Height,
                    Weight: rows_db[i].Weight,
                    Fitness: rows_db[i].Fitness,
                    MAX_HP: rows_db[i].MAX_HP,
                    Charisma: rows_db[i].Charisma,
                    Intelligence: rows_db[i].Intelligence,
                    Agily: rows_db[i].Agily
                    //you get the idea
                    });
               };//for
```

Now let's say i want to pull the Charisma Value for the user who just posted and i have their id stored as the virable uid

```
settings.UserList.get(uid).Strength
```

Lastly lets say i want a count of total users

```
settings.UserList.size;
```